# Pagination info missing after using where in laravel collection

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set a distance variable inside a collection and again filtering the collection with collection where using the distance as reference. But after the collection is filtered the pagination meta and links information are gone. So how to preserve the pagination info and use the where in collection. Here is my code.

```
$items = $items->paginate(15);

foreach($items as $item){
    $distance = $this->itemSearchService->findDistance($item->post_code, $request->post_code);
    $item->setAttribute('distance', $distance);
}

if(isset($request->distance)){
    $items = $items->where('distance', '<=', $request->distance);
}

return new ItemSearchListCollection($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to `paginate` after you have performed your filtering. You can then also add the [`withQueryString()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values) method to your `items` to preserve the query string.

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $distance = $this->itemSearchService->findDistance($item->post_code, $request->post_code);
    $item->setAttribute('distance', $distance);
}

if(isset($request->distance)){
    $items = $items->where('distance', '<=', $request->distance);
}

return new ItemSearchListCollection($items->paginate(15)->withQueryString());
```

Comment: Yes I want to paginate after I performed filtering. I am using the key as a reference to filter which is only available in the collection which i have set after running query.